# jQuery datatable footer with total rows from the ajax output

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to use the fnFooterCallback to sum the amounts in a column as a total, the part that I can not figure out yet is, that I need the total for that page which I'm getting fine from the aaData.

Any idea on how to display the footer with the output we got in aaData using ajax output?

Comment: Looking just for the same. If you found it, please let me know (by answering your question).

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I give it a shot.

In order to display in the footer, place this code after the `<thead>` and `<tbody>`

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th>Total:</th> 
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

So it can be displayed in the footer.

Than add this to the initiation:

```
"fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
    /*
     * Calculate the total market share for all browsers in this table (ie inc. outside
     * the pagination)
     */
    var iTotalMarket = 0;
    for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
    {
        iTotalMarket += aaData[i][1]*1;
    }

    /* Calculate the market share for browsers on this page */
    var iPageMarket = 0;
    for ( var i=iStart ; i<iEnd ; i++ )
    {
        iPageMarket += aaData[ aiDisplay[i] ][1]*1;
    }

    /* Modify the footer row to match what we want */
    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
    nCells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(iPageMarket);
}
```

change the number in the `aaData[i][1]` to which column you want to calculate (starting by 0, not by 1).

Note: This won't work if you have a special character in the row, will need to cut it.

Comment: Thank you! I had to update footer for ajaxed datatable. I was returning a json object with sum of few fields. I used your solution as a base. Didn't know how to access that specific "total sum json object" I returned from ajax in "fnFooterCallback", So just modified jquery.datatable.js to manage assigning it to global variable and used in this callback. Thank you, once again! :)

Comment: When I try this, nRow is undefined and it of course crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This code also works and its easier to use and understand:

add this to your blade view:

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
       <th>Total:</th> 
       <th></th>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```

The numbers of th depends on your quantity of rows.

The in your js add this footerCallback

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                        var api = this.api(), data;


                        var intVal = function ( i ) {
                            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                                typeof i === 'number' ?
                                    i : 0;
                        };

                        // This is for the Total text
                        var col0 = api
                            .column( 0 )
                            .data()
                            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                            }, 0 ); 
                    //First, please note var name col1 and we use it then
                    var col1 = api
                        .column( 1 )
                        .data()
                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0 );

                    $( api.column( 0 ).footer() ).html('Total');
                    // Here you can add the rows
                    $( api.column( 1 ).footer() ).html(col1); 
                    },
```

This code needs to be place just before

```
table.dataTable({
```

I hope this helps.